# Volume Rocker only controls Bluetooth In-call Volume; cannot control all other volumes

Tags: volume-control, bluetooth-audio

I am a bit baffled as to why the volume rocker is currently controlling "Bluetooth In-call Volume" I have not nor have  I ever paired a BT device with this phone. In fact I just always leave the BT signal off.

What else could be causing this and how do it change it so that my dedicated Volume button can control my music and not some Bluetooth thing that doesn't exist.

The phone is an LG Esteem, Android Ver 2.3.4